# Assigning a StrokeDashArray to a Line object cause 4004 Error

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I'm using SilverLight on Visual Studio 2008, Ver 3.5 SP1,

I have a small application that creates a new Line with a `StrokeDashArray`. I have created the `StrokeDashArray` and stored it in a helper class (together with other objects that get reused). The Line is assigned like this:

```
var myLine = new Line { 
    X1 = myHelperClass.X, 
    X2 = ..., 
    Y1 = ... 
    Y2 = ..., 
    Fill = myHelperclass.Fill, 
    StrokeThickness = myHelperclass.StrokeThickness, 
    Stroke = myHelperClass.Stroke, 
    StrokeDashArray = myHelperClass.StrokeDashArray
};

_parenCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
```

The object containing the line is in a class array. Depending on what the user selects it will draw the shapes on the canvas. Say I have `myDrawing1`, `myDrawing2` and user selects the first one, it draws fine. User then selects the second one, it draws fine, too. User then selects the first again and I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception ("Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Code: 4004. 
  Category: ManagedRuntimeError, 
  Message: System ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

If I rewrite the above `Line` assignment and put in `new DoubleCollection {5, 5}`, the code works fine.  I also checked all the values when I step through and they seem to be perfectly fine. I can't see any reason why the code fails on that line.

The reason I want to use the `StrokeDashArray` to be assigned from the helper class is so that the values can be customised during runtime. However, at the moment there is no customisation happening so it's exactly the same `StrokeDashArray` that is assigned to it on the first and subsequent assignments, and it always works the first time.

The values in `myHelperClass.StrokeDashArray[0]` and `myHelperClass.StrokeDashArray[1]` are always 5.0.  Anybody any idea what's going on here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some known bugs regarding the use of `StrokeDashArray` in Silverlight, for example you cannot assign a `StrokeDashArray` in a `Style` from code-behind. See the [following blog post with a workaround](http://gregdoesit.com/2010/09/setting-the-strokedasharray-using-a-style-in-silverlight/). You might have to use `DoubleCollection` rather than  `StrokeDashArray` in your helper class.

(This is quite an old bug, was initially reported in SL2.0!)

Comment: Thanks, got it fixed now by using the advise to assign the DoubleCollection as a string instead.  The strange thing though is why it always works the first time and only fails when it's reassigned with exactly the same code.

Comment: Yeah - it is a very nasty bug. Glad the workaround fixed it for you.

Comment: @JohnCambell remember to up upvote / accept answers. Many thanks.